# Dual citizenship uk/us. Moving back with family

Tags: relocation

I am a UK born that moved to US, married and became naturalized early this year. I've been in the US for 13 years. My husband is a US citizen by birth.  I have two elementary aged kids that I believe automatically have dual citizenship too.

We are looking into relocation to UK and what it would take.

1. Even though my kids are now dual citizens, is it truly automatic, or do we still have to apply/register them as UK citizens?  If we do have to apply, is this easier done before entering UK?
2. Which route should be taken to adjust my husband's status? And how soon would he be able to work?

Comment: To clarify Gayot Fow's answer on Q1: your children almost certainly have British citizenship automatically; they do not need to apply for it.  However, in order to prove it to an immigration officer at the border (or to anyone else), they'll need some kind of document, like a passport, and getting such a document does indeed require an application.  Before issuing the passport, the authorities will of course have to establish that the child is in fact a British citizen.  This is a determination that must be made with any first-time passport application, of course.

Answer (score 4):

**Q1. Even though my kids are now dual citizens, is it truly automatic, or do we still have to apply/register them as UK citizens? If we do have to apply, is this easier done before entering UK?**

As long as they have British passports, there's nothing more to do.  If they need British passports, you should apply on their behalf.  https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports

**Q2. Which route should be taken to adjust my husbands status? And how soon would he be able to work?**

He should apply for a spouse visa with you as the British sponsor.  See [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk) and the [financial requirement](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/452965/Immigration_Directorate_Instruction_Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement_August_2015.pdf).

He can work as soon as he arrives.